Flutter/Dart - The element type can't be assigned to the list type 'Bloc<dynamic>
I am totally new to Flutter/Dart and I am designing an app so I can practice. I am facing an error that I didn´t find here, neither ChatGPT could give me a proper solution.
Please, what´s going on?
main.dart
import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:you_flu/blocs/videos_bloc.dart';
import 'package:you_flu/screens/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(const YouFlu());

class YouFlu extends StatelessWidget {
  const YouFlu({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      blocs: [VideosBloc()], //Error here
      dependencies: const [],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'YouFlu',
        home: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The error states that here: blocs: [VideosBloc()], The element type 'VideosBloc' can't be assigned to the list type 'Bloc<dynamic>'.dartlist_element_type_not_assignable
I already tried:
blocs: VideosBloc(),

so with, and without the brackets.
Here is my VideosBloc class
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart';
import 'package:you_flu/api.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:you_flu/models/video.dart';

class VideosBloc implements BlocBase {
  late Api api;
  late List<Video> videos;

  final StreamController _videosController = StreamController();
  Stream get outVideos => _videosController.stream;

  final StreamController _searchController = StreamController();
  Sink get inSearch => _searchController.sink;

  VideosBloc() {
    api = Api();

    _searchController.stream.listen(_search as void Function(dynamic event)?);
  }

  void _search(String search) async {
    videos = await api.search(search);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videosController.close();
    _searchController.close();
  }

  @override
  void addListener(VoidCallback listener) {}

  @override
  bool get hasListeners => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  void notifyListeners() {}

  @override
  void removeListener(VoidCallback listener) {}
}

ChatGPT told me that the implementation of the VideosBloc class looks good.
Oh, before I forget: Here is my pubspec.yaml so you guys can check the versions I´m using:
name: you_flu
description: "Youtube Flutter"
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.4 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  youtube_player_flutter: ^9.0.1
  http: ^1.2.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  bloc_pattern: ^3.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
   - images/

Well so, why can´t I assign my VideosBloc class to the blocs property on BlocProvider?
Thanks!

Well... I found the answer, and it was very very simple:
return BlocProvider(
  blocs: [
    Bloc((i) => VideosBloc())
  ],
  // other stuff...
  ),
);

Create a list using the brackets, and then use a function from the Bloc class to assign my VideosBloc class to a Bloc.
